# Как выбирать какие джобы запускать в gitlab ci?

Tags: gitlab-ci

У меня есть репо **ci-config** в нем есть папочка templates где написаны джобы. И есть файлик project.yml в корне репы, в него я подключаю джобы.

**project.yml:**

```
include:
  - local: 'templates/parsing.ci.yml'
  - local: 'templates/docker.ci.yml'

stages:
  - docker
  - parsing
```

Как мне составлять файл **.gitlab-ci.yml** и в нем указывать только те джобы которые нужно выполнить? Сейчас он выглядит так

**.gitlab-ci.yml:**

```
include:
  - project: 'elma365-projects/common-ci-config'
    file: 'elma365-projects.yml'
```

Как мне указать так, что нужно выполнять только docker джобу?

**templates/parsing.ci.yml**

```
parse:
  stage: parsing
  allow_failure: true
  tags: 
    - docker
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:19.03.9-dind
  script:
    - apk add git --no-cache&& apk add openssh-client --no-cache
    - docker run --rm --mount src="$(pwd)",target=/app/repos,type=bind avatvar/elma365parser:dev
    - git config --global user.name ci-robot
    - git config --global user.email gitint-ci-robot@elma-bpm.com
    - git remote set-url origin https://ci-robot:$CI_ROBOT_PASSWORD@gitint.elewise.com/$CI_PROJECT_PATH.git
    - git add --all
    - git commit -m "add parsed files" && git push -u origin HEAD:${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}|| true
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
      exists:
        - '*.e365'
```

**templates/docher.ci.yaml**

```
docker-build:
  stage: docker
  tags:
    - docker
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - |
        if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH" ]]; then
          tag=""
          echo "Running on default branch '$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH': tag = 'latest'"
        else
          tag=":$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
          echo "Running on branch '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH': tag = $tag"
        fi
    - docker build -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
      exists:
        - Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, объявление job делать лучше в корневом ***gitlab-ci.yml*** для прозрачности конфигурации CI.
Поэтому, ответом на ваш вопрос будет перенос блока

```
stages:
  - docker
  - parsing
```

из **project.yml** в **gitlab-ci.ym** и уже там просто указываете только те джобы которые вам нужны:

```
stages:
  - docker
```

Comment: Но в таком случае получается ошибка https://i.imgur.com/saOQNAe.png

Comment: Приложите пожалуйста содержимое всех ваших yaml

Comment: Судя по всему у вас проблема с подключением файлов из проекта. Разберитесь сначала с расположением и правилом импорта из других проектов: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/